# Sony Xperia ZR wifi problem: wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, connection-issues, wpa2

I have a strange problem with Wi-Fi with my Sony Xperia. I can't connect to most of the networks I have tried, but the list of networks is ok (but somehow slowly loaded). **It stopped working suddenly after a week**. My previously used networks are all marked as "Saved", but when I try to connect the following happens:

1. Saved (doesn't even change when tapped)
2. Connecting -> Saved
3. Connecting -> Authentication problem -> Saved

This is what I have tried to fix it:

1. Restart phone
2. Restart phone, take out battery, SD card and SIM card
3. Restart wi-fi router
4. Connect to another network (sometimes works with some networks)
5. Forget network -> Type password again
6. Connect another Android device to the same network
7. Connect another non-android device to the same network
8. Change the router wireless settings to WEP, WPA and unsecured
9. Factory reset of the router
10. Sony Companion -> Repair
11. Factory reset of the phone

Router: D-Link DIR-615

Phone: Sony Xperia ZR C5502

Android version:
4.1.2

Baseband:

```
9x15A-ACEFWMAZQ-30110041-29
```

Build number:

```
10.1.1.A.1.310
```

Kernel:

```
3.4.0-g6df7905-02327-g1aa3092
BuildUser@BuildHost) )
#1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 11 11:17:13 2013
```

Log after turning on the wifi and trying to connect:

```
09-18 09:10:08.116: I/WifiManager(2391): Process ndroid.settings enabled Wifi
09-18 09:10:08.186: E/WifiHW(571): File "/data/misc/wifi/WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini" exists, not copying
09-18 09:10:08.497: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): nl80211: Don't connect to APs with RSSI < 0
09-18 09:10:08.497: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
09-18 09:10:08.497: I/ActivityManager(571): No longer want com.google.android.onetimeinitializer (pid 1747): hidden #51
09-18 09:10:08.637: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wapi_supplicant_init: Init WAI packet p2p0
09-18 09:10:08.637: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): Own MAC address: (Here's phone MAC address)
09-18 09:10:08.637: E/wpa_supplicant(3838):  Initialization: WAPI:set Staues=1
09-18 09:10:08.657: E/Diag_Lib(3838):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
09-18 09:10:08.757: E/wpa_supplicant(3838):  QMI_UIM_EVENT_REG_REQ_V01, qmi_err_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): QMI_UIM_GET_CARD_STATUS_REQ_V01, qmi_err_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].card_state: 0x1
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].error_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card READY
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].app_type : 0x2
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].app_state : 0x7
09-18 09:10:08.777: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card found
09-18 09:10:08.797: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): Reading GSM home network domain configuration file '/system/etc/wifi/gsm_domains.conf'
09-18 09:10:08.877: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): nl80211: Don't connect to APs with RSSI < -83
09-18 09:10:08.877: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
09-18 09:10:08.917: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wapi_supplicant_init: Init WAI packet wlan0
09-18 09:10:08.917: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): Own MAC address: (Here's phone MAC address)
09-18 09:10:08.917: E/wpa_supplicant(3838):  Initialization: WAPI:set Staues=1
09-18 09:10:08.957: E/wpa_supplicant(3838):  QMI_UIM_EVENT_REG_REQ_V01, qmi_err_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): QMI_UIM_GET_CARD_STATUS_REQ_V01, qmi_err_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].card_state: 0x1
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].error_code: 0x0
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card READY
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].app_type : 0x2
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card_info[i].app_state : 0x7
09-18 09:10:08.977: E/wpa_supplicant(3838): card found
09-18 09:10:09.037: E/WifiConfigStore(571): Failed to look-up a string: W
09-18 09:10:09.037: E/WifiConfigStore(571): Failed to look-up a string: SMS4
09-18 09:10:09.037: E/WifiConfigStore(571): Failed to look-up a string: SMS4
09-18 09:10:09.077: I/WifiManager(2391): Process ndroid.settings requested an active scan
09-18 09:10:09.087: E/Parcel(334): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
09-18 09:10:09.087: E/Parcel(334): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
09-18 09:10:09.097: E/Parcel(334): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
09-18 09:10:09.097: I/SuperStamina-WifiAnalyzer(571): WiFi is ON.
09-18 09:10:09.117: E/wifidirect(3726): onStartCommand 1
09-18 09:10:09.117: E/wifidirect(3726): Exitting file transfer service.
09-18 09:10:09.117: W/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
09-18 09:10:09.117: W/wpa_supplicant(3838): p2p0: Failed to initiate AP scan
09-18 09:10:09.127: E/wifidirect(3726): onStartCommand 1
09-18 09:10:09.127: E/wifidirect(3726): Exitting file transfer service.
09-18 09:10:10.128: W/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
09-18 09:10:11.119: W/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
09-18 09:10:12.130: W/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
09-18 09:10:12.811: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Trying to associate with (here is my router MAC) (SSID='smartus@unifi' freq=2427 MHz)
09-18 09:10:14.023: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=(here is my router MAC) status_code=1
09-18 09:10:19.088: I/WifiManager(2391): Process ndroid.settings requested an active scan
09-18 09:10:22.812: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Authentication with (here is router MAC) timed out.
```

These lines will later repeat:

```
09-18 09:10:12.811: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Trying to associate with (here is my router MAC) (SSID='smartus@unifi' freq=2427 MHz)
09-18 09:10:14.023: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=(here is my router MAC) status_code=1
09-18 09:10:19.088: I/WifiManager(2391): Process ndroid.settings requested an active scan
09-18 09:10:22.812: I/wpa_supplicant(3838): wlan0: Authentication with (here is router MAC) timed out.
```

Any ideas what could cause CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT? I believe this is usually happening when the network is congested (there are only 3 devices, 2 of them work. The phone won't work in the network alone neither).

Comment: Usually that event is sent by the router (as you wrote, when the network is congested). Googling a little also showed cert problems as possible reason. Only thing you did not yet factory-reset is your Android device; maybe something got messed up there? As connecting to other networks only "sometimes works", this is a more likely cause than all of those APs being "broken". If there's nothing else left, you could try to factory-reset your Xperia.

Comment: Factory reset doesn't help neither. Also I did the repair using the companion before which flashes the rom. That should be equal to the factory reset, right? Certificates problem, hm, I am not aware of using any certs...

Comment: Also I strongly believe that the problem is in the phone (HW or SW). I am trying to find the problem so when I get to the service centre, I can give them not just the device, but pinpoint the problem exactly...

Comment: Certs are used by WPA automatically if I understood that part correctly, i.e. I take it they refer to the "key files" exchanged. And yes, I fully agree the culprit must be on the Xperia, whether hard- or software. As you've already tried a factory-reset, the service centre is a very good idea: they should have a WiFi AP, and with some luck can reproduce the issue (unless that's one of those few networks where it does work, you know [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any definitive answer what is wrong from the service centre. They tried flashing some special ROM they had, but same result. They closed the issue with the conclusion it is a HW problem in the phone.

Comment: So did they repair it for you? I mean the phone must be in warranty? So, how did it finally work out?

Comment: @NikhilKhandelwal Full story here: http://android.kul.is/2013/09/sony-xperia-zr-wifi-problem.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an official solution I found after weeks of testing and research. In the end, the driver is not loaded properly or by default, custom ROM created the havoc.

I noticed that when running ADB GUI, there is this file missing from `/system/data/misc/wifi` called `WCNSS_qcom_cfg.ini` .

I'm using ADB Helper Version 4.2.0.0, under build.prop Viewer tab, choose `wlan.driver.config` it points to that location. I downloaded it from somewhere on the Xperia developer forum website. Then I modified and modified until I found the solution.

In this file I modified the line `gDotMode=3` (which is running in N mode only) to either 1 or 2 which s "a" or "b" mode.

I rebooted the device and the wifi works and N mode is disabled meaning you wont be able to connect in 5GHz mode anymore. But you will be able to connect to all the CURRENT 2.4GHz AP.

I read somewhere where ICS android allows you to Enable or Disable 5GHz scanning of AP. But was removed from later versions.

Now, my phone can connect to any 2.4GHz WiFi.